# Find a point further up on the steepest slope line in 3 dimensions?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

## I can find the coordinates of point **B** on the slope line in 2 dimensions. How do I find a similar point on the steepest tangent line in 3 dimensions?

Starting with a point **A** with coordinates $\left(x_0,f(x_0)\right)$ that lies on a function **f** I can find an other point **B**.

**B** lies on the tangent line at **A**.
$$ \left(x_0+ h,  f(x_0)+h\frac{df}{dx}       \right)$$

[image]

What is the 3 dimensional analogue of this?

I suspect it is something similar to **B3** below:

$$A_3\rightarrow\left(x_0,y_0,f(x_0,y_0)\right)$$
$$B_3\rightarrow\left(x_0+h,y_0+g,f(x_0,y_0)+h \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+g\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)$$

As an example I used the function $$f_3(x,y)=\sin(x)\cos(y)$$

The line segment between the two points should be perpendicular to the contours. But my incorrect **B** lands to the left of where it should be for **A**=$\left(0,0,f_3(0,0) \right)$
[image]

[image]

Comment: The problem is that in three dimensions there is not a single tangent line, but an infinite number of them. There's one tangent plane though, but you still have to specify a direction to go in.

Comment: I meant to say "steepest tangent line!" will edit the question now. thank you

Comment: If you do a websearch for "steepest ascent" l bet you'll find an answer. Then, you can come back here and post it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Gradient Ascent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent) computes the correct direction of steepest ascent.

$$A\rightarrow B$$
$$\left(x_0,y_0,f\left(x_0,y_0\right)\right)\rightarrow \left(x_0+h\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},y_0+h\frac{\partial f}{\partial y},f\left(x_0+h\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},y_0+h\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)\right)$$
$$X\rightarrow h\nabla X$$

[image]

> ---

## Gradient Ascent doesn't give you another point on the same line.

Instead it gives you another point in the correct direction but below the line on the surface of $f$.

Below is a modified gradient ascent that gives you another point **B** on the steepest tangent line. Unfortunate it varies its position on the tangent line as a function of the slope.

$$\left(x_0,y_0,f\left(x_0,y_0\right)\right)\rightarrow \left(x_0+h\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},y_0+h\frac{\partial f}{\partial y},f\left(x_0\right)+h\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+h\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)$$

[image]

Comment: Please tell by which tool you are drawing those graphics.

Comment: @jiten "Mathematica", in conjunction with "Ink2Go", Ink2Go is a macintosh application that lets you draw on anything